# How to give Flutter SDK Path in Android Studio on Mac os, How to update Flutter SDK path in MACOS?

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have installed the Android studio and the plugin's DART,FLUTTER to kickstart the flutter but as i am not able to give path of sdk while creating my very first project for flutter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tried to find out the solution did not got solution.. 
Finally this are the steps i have implemented and works for me. 
Prerequisites :-

1. Install Android studio
2. Install plugins to kick start flutter projects (DART,FLUTTER)

You can find out this inside  **android studio --> preferences --> Plugins**

**Now you have to setup Flutter SDK path to your Android studio**

1. Download the [Flutter SDK](https://flutter.io/get-started/install/)
2. Extract it where do you want (for example - **/Users/vrushali/Downloads/flutter**)
3. Open your Android studio --> start a new Flutter Project --> select default application --> next --> select flutter sdk path --> browse to the . location where you have download and extract your flutter sdk --> select the flutter --> bin --> and say okay
   All set..! Your project will get created in some time :)

Comment: Yes because since yesterday was solving.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Theres a better way if you want to skip

> Open your Android studio --> start a new Flutter Project --> select
>   default application --> next --> select flutter sdk path --> browse to
>   the . location where you have download and extract your flutter sdk
>   --> select the flutter --> bin

doing every time you open android project

Step1:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Step2 paste

```
PATH="/Users/vrushali/Downloads/flutter/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This will add the path permanently

Answer (score 4):

**asdf**

If you have used [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to install **Flutter SDK**.

You can find the location of the flutter by using the following commands,

1. Open the location of **asdf** in terminal

   ```
   open ~/.asdf
   ```
2. Inside the `.asdf` folder go to `installs` folder and then to `flutter` folder. Inside the `flutter` folder will find the current version of the **Flutter SDK** as the folder name.

   For example, in my case the folder name is `1.12.13+hotfix.7-stable` and the path to the folder is `/Users/akarshseggemu/.asdf/installs/flutter/1.12.13+hotfix.7-stable`

Comment: Alternatively, you can run `asdf which flutter` command in your terminal to get the path to currently active Flutter SDK in your local machine.

Comment: `asdf which flutter` will actually take you to the flutter executable, `asdf where flutter` will take you to the actual location of the configured version of flutter sdk you are using with asdf. So I ended up adding the following to my zsh environment variables

`export FLUTTER_ROOT=$(asdf where flutter)`

Answer (score 3):

**This worked for me (for ZSH users)**

> Open terminal & run this command

```
touch $HOME/.zshrc
```

> Run this command

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

> Type the path like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Path to your extracted flutter/Flutter/bin
```

> Press ctrl+x then press y Press Enter Close the terminal and open a
> new terminal and run this command

```
flutter --version
```

Comment: But I don't know the path! That's the problem...

Comment: to know the path just go the directory where you have downloaded the flutter sdk and then copy that path and append it in the above line which I mentioned in the answer and save

Comment: The problem was that I hadn't downloaded the Flutter SDK. I had only downloaded the plugin from the plugins marketplace inside Android Studio, and I thought that was enough!...  So I was trying to find out where Android Studio had put it, and it wouldn't tell me! But once I realized that the plugin was not the same as the SDK, I went and downloaded the SDK, and the problem was solved! 

Comment: Good to know you have resolved the problem @KarolinaHagegård

Answer (score 2):

```
For update flutter SDK path in Mac,

1. First your default shell using echo $SHELL command in Terminal.
2. Use below commane to open vim editor and update Path.
    - if it is Bash then type vim $HOME/.bash_profile or vim $HOME/.bashrc 
    - if Z shell then type vim $HOME/.zshrc
3. Type i to enter INSERT mode (or esc to exit INSERT mode).
4. Type export PATH="$PATH:[YOUR_PATH]/flutter/bin" replacing [YOUR_PATH] with the path to the folder where you moved the flutter folder earlier ex. export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Your_User/Your_Dev_Folder/flutter/bin"
5. Type esc, then :wq! to save and exit.
6. Quit the Terminal and open it again to refresh.
7. Type echo $PATH to check that the path was correctly added.       
8. Type which flutter to verify the flutter command is available.       
9. Type flutter --version to check the Flutter version.
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this really helpful. 
In order to get it work, I had to navigate to my development directory and entered echo $PATH. 
I then copied the full path and replaced everything after the colon and before the closing quotation; PATH="$PATH:[here]". 
Thereafter, I pressed the esc key and typed : followed by wq!.
That's what worked for me. THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the people that made the flutter plugin and they helped me out. For making flutter work with your IDE (haven't done this in Android but have in VScodium or Vscode).

In command line:
asdf where flutter

In a text document:

export FLUTTER_ROOT="$/asdf/where/flutter/answer/should/go/here"

Add that to your bash_profile **above** the asdf part. Or your asdf installation won't work.
With nano: ctrl+o, enter, ctrl+x.

Give your IDE the path to the installation, it should work. If not, the change needs to take effect, restart your computer.

Answer (score -4):

Just provide the location where your saved flutter software.