# About setting Flutter SDK path on Mac

Tags: macos, flutter, sdk

I initially set the sdk path to '~/development/flutter'.
I later changed it to '~/flutter/bin' and it gives me problems

If i set the path to '~flutter/bin' when creating an app in flutter for the first time, the error 'Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location' appears and the project cannot be created. It's possible.

What's wrong? Plz help me.......

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2J41.png)

Comment: Choose only flutter path not bin,
And to update flutter sdk path in Mac follow this below Link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68710889/10823147